# Evaluate Jms Destination Dynamically from header using JmsSendingMessageHandler

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration

I am trying to send message using `JmsSendingMessageHandler` but could not find a method which would fetch destination value from header something like `messageHandler.setDestinationExpressionString("headers['destination_name']")` ?

```
@MessagingGateway
public interface OutboundMessageGateway {

    @Gateway(requestChannel = "outMessageChannel")
    void sendMessage(Message<?> message);

}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "outMessageChannel" )
private MessageHandler jmsOutboundHandler() {
        JmsSendingMessageHandler messageHandler = new JmsSendingMessageHandler(new JmsTemplate(connectionFactory());
        messageHandler.setDestinationExpressionString("headers['destination_name']"); // not available
        return messageHandler;
    }
```

any solution ? I want to fetch destination dynamically from header I am passing with `Message<?>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API like that `JmsSendingMessageHandler.setDestinationExpressionString()`. Not sure why your IDE doesn't suggest you that you are on a wrong way, but there is other choice. My one shows this:

[image]

If you are really sure that you set that `destination_name` upstream, then you indeed can use that `setDestinationExpression(Expression)` API and like this:

```
handler.setDestinationExpression(new SpelExpressionParser().parseExpression("headers['destination_name']"));
```

Another, more Java-way is like this:

```
handler.setDestinationExpression(new FunctionExpression<Message<?>>(m -> m.getHeaders().get("destination_name")));
```

I think we can add that `setDestinationExpressionString()` anyway, if you insist and can contribute such a fix back to the framework: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/main/CONTRIBUTING.adoc

Comment: it worked ! thanks for your help :) I'll go through the docs and will see if I can contribute back to the framework